# Define a class for a complex type

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm using php's `SoapClient`. My `classmap` works *except* when I encounter this particular complex type:

```
<xs:complexType mixed="true" name="Text">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="values" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="a" type="ti:a"/>
        <xs:element ref="ti:br"/>
        <xs:element name="strong" type="ti:strong"/>
        <xs:element name="ul" type="ti:ul"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

**How would I define a PHP class for this?**

I've tried the obvious but without any success. Class members are always `null`

```
class Text
{
    protected $values = null;
    protected $a = null;
    protected $br = null;
    protected $strong = null;
    protected $ul = null;

    public function __construct($values, $a, $br, $strong, $ul)
    {
      $this->values = $values;
      $this->a = $a;
      $this->br = $br;
      $this->strong = $strong;
      $this->ul = $ul;
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the WSDL https://content-staging.travcorp.com/ccapi/v3/CCAPIv3.wsdl

I'd appreciate some help. I can provide more code but hopefully you get the problem.

I'm guessing that I'm not handling `<xs:choice />` further up the class hierarchy.